# How to identify transmission issues

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, camry

I have a new Camry L (4 cylinder 5 gear)with about 6k miles on it. Whenever I push the car from 0 to 30 mph and then let go easy on the gas to keep the car at 30-35, then I can feel the car 'jerking' (shifting gears). I had an old chevy malibu (2.2 ltrs) with about 120k on it and it had the exact same 'jerks'. Just that the jerks in the Malibu were way more stronger than what I feel in my Camry. I have never driven a new sedan before so I don't know if this indeed is a transmission issue. None of the sensor lights on the dashboard are on. How could I know for sure that my transmission is alright ?

I have taken it to the dealership and those fellas say this is normal car function. I just dont know if thats the truth.

Answer (score 2):

Depends wildy on your definition of "jerks". Hard jerks can be fluid pressure problems in the shift solenoids that cause rough shifting. Light jerks are pretty normal on torque-converter equipped, or even automated manual vehicles if they shift while you are modulating the throttle.

Does this jerk happen if you keep the throttle steady, or just when you accelerate and let off?

Comment: Dont know how to measure the jerk. say you are in a stick shift and at 50 mph (driving in 4th gear) you put the gear in 2nd. You can feel the hard shift of the gear change. Feel me ? This happens just when I accelerate and let off.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty hard jerk.